# MIPS with Mars how to read values after pressing enter?

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

How could i read values so i can store them in memory after? I need to get the user to input values and then press enter so i can get those values and work with them.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use service 5 to read an integer, 6 to read a float, 7 for a double and service 8 to read a string. See MARS [reference](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html) for syscall services provided.

Here goes an example that reads an integer and a string from console and holds the results in variables `number` and `buffer`:

```
.data
  number: .word 0
  buffer: .space 80

 .text
   li $v0, 5 # service 5 reads integer from console
   syscall

   sw $v0, number # Store read integer into number
   li $v0, 8 # service 8 reads a string
   la $a0, buffer
   li $a1, 80  # buffer size
   syscall  # input text will be stored in buffer 

   li $v0, 7  # service 7 reads double
   syscall # $f0-$f1 contains the double read
   mov.d $f2, $f0
   syscall # read another double

   div.d $f12, $f2, $f0  # Divide the first double by the second double
   li $v0, 3
   syscall  # Print result of division
```

Comment: can you tell me how can i use the 7 for the syscall to get a double and then make some dividing between them?

Comment: that was awesome help now please show me how do i compare if $f12 is smaller than $f8 then go to label EXAMPLE ... i tryed using 

c.lt.d $f12,$f8 
   bc1t EXAMPLE

Comment: @AndréAlvarez: That is correct. You have to compare issuing `c.lt.d $f12, $f8` which sets coprocessor 1 flag 0 to true if `$f12` is less than `$f8` and then issue `bc1t label` to branch to `label` when coprocessor 1 flag 0 is true

Comment: but it doesnt work... how can i send you the code so you can see it? its a program to calculate the weight then divide by the hight of a person x hight again if its lower than 20 the person is thin, if its between 20-25 its normal and above 25 is fat... i have done all this except the last part conditionals...